# how to accept all the answers from form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

this is my form in which i am conducting a quiz

```
<form action="test" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for question in questions %}
    {{question.question}}
    <input type="radio" id="1" name="{{question.qno}}" value="1">:{{question.option1}}<br>
    <input type="radio" id="2" name="{{question.qno}}" value="2">:{{question.option2}}<br>
    <input type="radio" id="3" name="{{question.qno}}" value="3">:{{question.option3}}<br>
    <input type="radio" id="4" name="{{question.qno}}" value="4">:{{question.option4}}<br>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

there are multiple questions generated on the screen as per my database. I have to accept all the values and pass it to my views.py for further processing how to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find all the values inside the request.POST dictionary for fbv or self.request.POST for cbv.

```
value1 = request.POST.get(name1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll find all the values inside the request.POST dictionary for fbv or self.request.POST for cbv.

e.g. value1 = request.POST.get(name1)